# Speed up jQuery manipulation of a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, dom, optimization

My application has a long list of objects whose width needs to be modified via jQuery. Currently I'm using code like this:

```
$('#my_list div.text_field').each(function() {
  // Cache objects we're going to use multiple times.
  var $textField = $(this);
  var $listContents = $textField.closest('div.list_contents');

  // Find widths.
  var contentsWidth = $listContents.outerWidth();
  var avatarsWidth = $listContents.find('div.avatars').outerWidth();
  var tagsWidth = $listContents.find('div.tags').outerWidth();
  var textLeft = $textField.position().left;

  // Update the width.
  var newTextWidth = contentsWidth - textLeft - avatarsWidth - tagsWidth;
  $textField.css({ width: newTextWidth });
});
```

However, it takes a while (> 1 second) when there are hundreds of objects to be manipulated. Any idea how I could make this faster? Should I totally eschew jQuery and use native JS?

Comment: I think that the DOM manipulation (setting the new widths) is what takes the most time - not jQuery. You could try to [detach](http://jqapi.com/#p=detach) a parent object of the items you want to resize prior to changing the widths and reattach it afterwards. This prevents the browser from recalculating and rerendering after each change.

Comment: Okay, I'm caching all the widths I calculate, then detaching the parent element from the DOM and applying the widths that I cached, then reattaching it to the DOM. This has speed things up by about 33%. The calculation aspect is still taking quite a long time though.

Comment: try to use a profiler like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to analyze where the most work is done

Comment: If you have Firebug or are using Google Chrome, add `console.profile()` before the start of the code and `console.profileEnd()` to after the end of the code. This will create a profile that you can look at to work out where the slowness is coming from. You may find that it's actually all the browser doing normal work (calculating sizes etc) (shown as Program in Chrome) rather than actual javascript work. This is particularly the case if you have a lot of rows in (say) a table, and you decide to `display:none` a bunch of them. The browser has to re-calculate the table layout/size.

Comment: Couldn't get console.profile() working (although, admittedly, I didn't try very hard), so I've just been using new Date() before and after the function to time it. I've done some more testing, and the vast majority of the slowness is from jQuery's outerWidth() function. Replacing lines that call outerWidth() with an integer reduces the time from ~2000 ms to ~30 ms. Jesus.

Comment: I'm wondering if js is really the right place to be doing this logic... are all of the elements present on initial load? could you do some of this server side? Even if you see a speed increase you still have to worry about memory consumption and users with less powerful browsers.

Comment: Well, it's purely front-end code. I basically have a bunch of rows full of elements: text, avatars, and tags. I want all of those rows to be the same length, and I'm doing that by resizing the "text" element of each row. However, the width I set that element to will be different for each row, depending on the width of the other elements in the row. Soooo, long story short, what *should* be responsible for this is probably CSS. But CSS can't do this, unless I use tables, perhaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, through a series of improvements I was able to whittle the time it takes to run this code (on Chrome 18 on a series of ~600 items) down from over 3000 ms to 70ms.

The most drastic improvement came from using offsetWidth on the raw HTML elements instead of jQuery's outerWidth() statement. That alone shaved off over 50% of the time:

```
avatarsWidth = $listContents.find('div.avatars')[0].offsetWidth;
```

The second most drastic change came from reducing the number of DOM modifications I made. In the code above, I was looping through elements, calculating their widths, and then immediately applying these widths to the DOM. In my improved code, I still loop through to calculate the widths, however I then *store* those widths, detach the elements from the DOM, apply the stored widths, and reattach them. Thanks to @muffel for this idea. This shaved off over 30% of the total time:

```
$('#my_list div.text_field').each(function() {
  var $textField = $(this);
  // ...
  var newTextWidth = contentsWidth - textLeft - avatarsWidth - tagsWidth;
  $textField.attr('data-width', newTextWidth);
});

$('#my_list')
  .detach()
  .find('div.text_field')
    .each(function() {
      $(this).css({ width: $(this).attr('data-width') });
    })
    .end()
  .appendTo('#container');
```

The third biggest improvement came from reducing the number of times I traversed the DOM. Instead of selecting elements each time through the loop, I selected them all up front and then referenced the indices inside the loop. This made up the majority of the remaining improvement:

```
var $avatars = $('#my_list .avatars');
// ...
$('#my_list div.text_field').each(function(i) {
  // ...
  avatarsWidth = $avatars.eq(i).offsetWidth;
  // ...
});
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Yeah, it makes you wait for 2 days though.

Answer (score 0):

for starters you shouldnt need to encase this with a $(this)... unless im missing something (which i might be) you should be able to just use "this" in each $textfield context... that will save you a function call and a var creation. Also move the var declarations out of the function... that will save more cycles too. Let me know if that speeds things up a bit.

Comment: Okay, I moved the var declarations outside. I also did some tests on $(this), and it is indeed faster to store it in a variable and refer to that variable rather than to continually reuse $(this). Of course, for a minimal number of calls the time savings are minimal, but if you have a function that calls $(this) hundreds of times, caching it instead could yield significant performance improvements, because that's one less function you're calling over and over again.